# Numpy array modifying multiple elements at once

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have three numpy arrays:

```
row = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])

# a is a subset of row:

a = np.array([1, 5])

# b is an array that I use to change some elements in the first row array:

b = np.array([10, 550])
```

What I need to do is to change **in one shot** the elements of the row array that are present in a with the correspondent b elements.

i.e.:

```
>> modified_row
array([10, 2, 3, 4, 500])
```

Doing this in a naive way would be:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    row[np.where(row==a[i])]= b[i]
```

I would like a solution like;

```
row[np.where(row==a)] = b
```

But that doesn't work...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you clarify your expected behaviour for repeated elements?

Comment: @wim, the fact is that for my problem, all elements are unique and sorting is not a problem, since those values are indexes by themselves.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please note @Jaime's answer is better - this was marked as correct despite it relying on the ordering of the elements. Here is a working version that does not modify `row` in-place but otherwise will work in the general case. At the end of this post is my original answer.

```
import numpy as np

def replaced(row, a, b):
    row_order = row.argsort()
    a_order = a.argsort()

    sorted_row = row[row_order]
    sorted_a = a[a_order]
    sorted_b = b[a_order]

    sorted_row[np.in1d(sorted_row, sorted_a)] = sorted_b

    # return results in original order
    return sorted_row[row_order.argsort()]

a = np.array([1, 5])
b = np.array([10, 550])

row = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
print replaced(row, a, b)

row = np.array([5,4,3,2,1])
print replaced(row, a, b)

row = np.array([4, 5, 1, 3, 2])
print replaced(row, a, b)
```

results:

```
>>> row = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> print replaced(row, a, b)
[ 10   2   3   4 550]
>>> 
>>> row = np.array([5,4,3,2,1])
>>> print replaced(row, a, b)
[550   4   3   2  10]
>>> 
>>> row = np.array([4, 5, 1, 3, 2])
>>> print replaced(row, a, b)
[  4 550  10   3   2]
```

**ORIGINAL INCORRECT ANSWER**

One way to do this is with the `in1d` function, which will generate a boolean array that you can use to index `row` as shown below.

Note that you may have problems with this (and other methods) if the elements of `row` are not unique or if you have repeated elements in `a`

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> row = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> a = np.array([1, 5])
>>> b = np.array([10, 550])
>>> np.in1d(row, a)
array([ True, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> row[np.in1d(row, a)] = b
>>> row
array([ 10,   2,   3,   4, 550])
```

You can normally use whatever index/boolean array you originally used to extract `a` for this purpose too.

Comment: You are assuming that all arrays are sorted, your solution wouldn't work properly with `a = [5, 1]`, as it would put the values from `b` in the wrong positions.

Comment: @Jaime you are right - OP you should remove the accepted flag from this post.

Comment: np.in1d would work with some careful argsorting, but I don't have time to change it right this minute

Answer (score 5):

If you don't have guarantees on the sorting of your arrays, you could have a reasonably efficient implementation using `np.searchsorted`:

```
def find_and_replace(array, find, replace):
    sort_idx = np.argsort(array)
    where_ = np.take(sort_idx, 
                     np.searchsorted(array, find, sorter=sort_idx))
    if not np.all(array[where_] == find):
        raise ValueError('All items in find must be in array')
    row[where_] = b
```

The only thing that this can't handle is repeated entries in `array`, but other than that it works like a charm:

```
>>> row = np.array([5,4,3,2,1])
>>> a = np.array([5, 1])
>>> b = np.array([10, 550])
>>> find_and_replace(row, a, b)
>>> row
array([ 10,   4,   3,   2, 550])

>>> row = np.array([5,4,3,2,1])
>>> a = np.array([1, 5])
>>> b = np.array([10, 550])
>>> find_and_replace(row, a, b)
>>> row
array([550,   4,   3,   2,  10])

>>> row = np.array([4, 5, 1, 3, 2])
>>> find_and_replace(row, a, b)
>>> row
array([  4, 550,  10,   3,   2])
```

Comment: What would we do, if we wanted to change values at indexes which are multiple of given n, like a[2],a[4],a[6],a[8]..... for n=2?

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility:

```
>>> row = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> row[np.any(row.reshape(-1, 1) == a, axis=1)] = b
>>> row
array([ 10,   2,   3,   4, 550])
```

The way this works is:

```
>>> row.reshape(-1, 1) == a
array([[ True, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False, False],
       [False,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> np.any(row.reshape(-1, 1) == a, axis=1)
array([ True, False, False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
```

And this boolean mask corresponds to the entries you want to replace.

The time and space complexity of this solution are pretty bad: Θ(*nm*) to replace *m* entries in an array of size *n* due to the large boolean mask. I don't recommend it over `in1d` for your specific use case, but it shows a detour that is useful in related cases.

Comment: yes these intermediate results can definitely be useful. I would suggest writing it as `np.any(row[..., None] == a, axis=1)` though. It always takes me longer to understand the reshape operations vs the explicit broadcasting.

Comment: @MrE: I guess it's a matter of taste; I'm used to the scikit-learn codebase, where `reshape(-1, 1)` is the common way to transpose a 1-d array. But `np.any` is a good idea, I should have thought of that myself.

Comment: What would we do, if we wanted to change values at indexes which are multiple of given n, like a[2],a[4],a[6],a[8]..... for n=2?

Answer (score 2):

An interesting alternative solution is to use `numpy.put` as documented [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put.html#numpy.put%20%22%22). In this case it is also important to think carefully about what will happen if there are duplicates in `row`. By default, `put` will cycle through the elements in b if there are more than two matches in this case.

```
import numpy as np
row = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
a = np.array([1, 5])
b = np.array([10, 550])
index_list = [np.where(row == element) for element in a]
np.put(row,index_list,b)
row
array([ 10,   2,   3,   4, 550]) #output
```

Edit: additional example to deal with index-based assignment query in comments:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> target_array = np.arange(50)
>>> n = 2 
>>> index_array = np.arange(0,len(target_array),n)
>>> b = np.array([10, 550])
>>> np.put(target_array, index_array, b)
>>> target_array #note that np.put cycles through the substitutions in b
array([ 10,   1, 550,   3,  10,   5, 550,   7,  10,   9, 550,  11,  10,
        13, 550,  15,  10,  17, 550,  19,  10,  21, 550,  23,  10,  25,
       550,  27,  10,  29, 550,  31,  10,  33, 550,  35,  10,  37, 550,
        39,  10,  41, 550,  43,  10,  45, 550,  47,  10,  49])
```

Comment: What would we do, if we wanted to change values at indexes which are multiple of given n, like a[2],a[4],a[6],a[8]..... for n=2?

Comment: I've added an example for that as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can now use [array.put](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.put.html)

```py
>>> a = np.arange(5)
>>> np.put(a, [0, 2], [-44, -55])
>>> a
array([-44,   1, -55,   3,   4])
```